# getting parameter value as undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Below is my code, I am getting the success msg when I send `data: abuse and remark`, but the `alert(uid, vid);` gives undefined. What is my mistake? I searched a lot but could not solve it

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#flag').click(function(){        
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          height: "auto"

        });
        $('#save').click( function savedata(uid ,vid){
                            abuse = $('#report_abuse :selected').text();
                   remark =  document.getElementById('motive').value;
                   var uid = this.uid;
                    var vid = this.vid;
                            alert(uid, vid);

                  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "tpl/main/process.php",
                        data: { abuse_data : abuse, remark_data : remark },
                            success: function(data){
                                alert('successful');
                        }
                });

            });
        });
      }); 
      </script>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
    $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];    
   $vid = $_SESSION['seen'];    
    }
    ?>
    <input type="button" name="save" id="save" value="Save" onclick="savedata('$uid', '$vid')"/>
```

Comment: There is nothing passed to the named function - there are no elements that have parameters like that. You can only pass the event. Looks like you retrofitted an existing function to the click. Please show where uid and vid should come from. Even if you COULD pass uid and vid to the function, it would not be `this.uid`

Comment: where is your savedata('$uid', 'vid') function and what is $uid in this code?

Comment: Is it intentional that your `click` handler for `#save` is inside the handler for `#flag`?

Comment: @halex yes after click on flag ,i get model in that I have save button

Answer (score 0):

You have retrofitted a function that does not work in the way you wish.

I do not see either uid or vid used in the function by the way, but if you need it this is how you use it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#save').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    var abuse = $('#report_abuse :selected').text(),
        remark =  $('#motive').val(),
        uid = $(this).data("uid"),
        vid = $(this).data("vid"); // where are they used?
    alert("uid:"+uid+" - vid:"+vid);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
       url: "tpl/main/process.php",
      data: { abuse_data : abuse, remark_data : remark },
      success: function(data){
        alert('successful');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

using

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
   $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];     
   $vid = $_SESSION['seen'];    
} ?>
<input type="button" name="save" id="save" value="Save" 
data-uid="<?php echo $uid ?>" data-vid="<?php echo $vid ?>" />
```

Comment: I am not getting any value for uid and vid

Comment: That is not a useful comment. What value are you not getting when and where. Do you have any console messages, perhaps I made a typo

Answer (score -1):

- alert both uid and vid and check what values you are getting, I think that you are getting undefined

Comment: As he said. Of course he is getting undefined, the values are not passed